# PHP Curl Multi (curl_multi) and proxies,

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, proxy

So,

I have an issue with needing to make multiple http requests (i mean 100's, even 1000's) using PHP, and these requests need to be run through a proxy to protect the server info/ip.

So, the problem is, to do these requests using php curl is perfectly fine, but takes a long time. If i use php curl_multi, it takes a lot less time. But if i introduce the PROXY to this, the curl_multi takes a significantly longer time than not using curl_multi (curl one after another).

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_REQUEST['url']);

//Proxy
$proxyStr = 'user:pass@123.123.123.123:80'; // username:password@ip:port
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyStr); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
$req = "something= somethingelse \r\n"; //request that needs to be sent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $req); // Query

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//This is some sample code, obviously the curl_multi is using curl_multi_init() and curl_multi_exec()
//Here is a sample code for curl_multi, just introduce the proxy code in the middle of it: http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/
```

My question is, what am i doing wrong? The curl_multi with proxy takes a HUGE amount of time longer regardless of if i use 2 at a time or 5 at a time. But using multi with 1 at a time is quicker (not quick enough but a LOT quicker than 2 or more).

As a poor man's multithreading, i added a worker script to the server which pretty much takes a http post and does a single curl on the data (post contains the proxy, so this worker uses the proxy). And using the main server, i use curl_multi to POST details to the worker script (about 2-5 requests at a time). This method works "better" but not a huge amount better. Eg. if i use curl_multi to send 10 requests 1 at a time to the worker, it finishes in ~10 secs. If i send 10 requests 5 at a time, it finished in ~8-9 Secs. So its definitely faster, but not as fast as i need it to be.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions on why this is the case?

Is there something about php curl_multi and proxies that im missing? And I assumed that multiple PHP requests coming INTO a server would execute in parallel (thus why i was reffering to curl_multi'ing into the worker script which does the proxy as a poor mans multithreading). Anyone suggesting on using pthreads, will that actually solve the problem (it is not practical for me to install pthreads, but from what i can see, i doubt it would solve the problem)?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but where is `curl_multi_exec` loop in your code? Other sample: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php or http://www.somacon.com/p537.php

Comment: explained in the 2nd to last code comment. the sample code is not for multi (its to show my other options), but multi is simply the start and the end. So yes, i am executing the curl_multi correctly.
Here is the sample code i use for curl multi (i just add my options in the middle of it): http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/

Comment: try caching the results of the get urls so you would have less time retrieving